# How do I perform a recursive directory search for strings within files in a UNIX TRU64 environment?

Tags: unix, find, grep, xargs

Unfortunately, due to the limitations of our Unix Tru64 environment, I am unable to use the GREP -r switch to perform my search for strings within files across multiple directories and sub directories.

Ideally, I would like to pass two parameters.  The first will be the directory I want my search is to start on.  The second is a file containing a list of all the strings to be searched.  This list will consist of various directory path names and will include special characters:

ie:
/aaa/bbb/ccc
/eee/dddd/ggggggg/
etc..

The purpose of this exercise is to identify all shell scripts that may have specific hard coded path names identified in my list.

There was one example I found during my investigations that perhaps comes close, but I am not sure how to customize this to accept a file of string arguments:

eg:  find etb -exec grep test {} \;

where 'etb' is the directory and 'test', a hard coded string to be searched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

`find dir -type f -exec grep -F -f strings.txt {} \;`

`dir` is the directory from which searching will commence

`strings.txt` is the file of strings to match, one per line

`-F` means treat search strings as literal rather than regular expressions

`-f strings.txt` means use the strings in `strings.txt` for matching

You can add `-l` to the grep switches if you just want filenames that match.

**Footnote:**

Some people prefer a solution involving `xargs`, e.g.

`find dir -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -F -f strings.txt`

which is perhaps a little more robust/efficient in some cases.

Comment: @tchrist: what makes you think you need `xargs` ?

Comment: @PaulR: need is a strong word. Of course  you don't **need** it, but it saves very seriously on how many instances of a program you `exec`.

Comment: @tchrist: sounds like **premature optimisation** to me. ;-)

Comment: Paul, I am not sure if you got the last message I sent you.

Comment: Wanted to thank you for your solution.  It works, but I have chosen to use the second method you suggested, as it provides me with the name and path of the script as well.

Comment: I just would like to tweak it a little now.  How can I search for comment lines (‘#’ in position 1) and filter these out first.  I would like to then feed that result set into the rest of my search.  The reason I want this done is because I have identified many instances where strings I am searching for exist within comment lines of scripts only.  I am not interested in these and want to limit the number of hits I am currently receiving.

Comment: @Evan: to filter out comment lines just add another grep with the `-v` flag, e.g. `find dir -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -F -f strings.txt | grep -v "^#"`

Answer (score 1):

By reading, I assume we can not use the [gnu coreutil](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/), and egrep is not available.
I assume (for some reason) the system is broken, and escapes do not work as expected.

Under normal situations, `grep -rf patternfile.txt /some/dir/` is the way to go.

> a file containing a list of all the strings to be searched

Assumptions : gnu coreutil not available. grep -r does not work. handling of special character is broken.

Now, you have working awk ? no ?. It makes life so much easier. But lets be on the safe side.

Assume : working `sed` ,one of `od` OR `hexdump` OR `xxd` (from vim package) is available.

Lets call this patternfile.txt

---

### 1. Convert list into a regexp that grep likes

Example patternfile.txt contains

> /foo/
>
> /bar/doe/
>
> /root/

(example does not print special char, but it's there.) we must turn it into something like

`(/foo/|/bar/doe/|/root/)`

Assuming `echo -en` command is not broken, and `xxd` , or `od`, or `hexdump` is available,

Using hexdump

`cat patternfile.txt |hexdump -ve '1/1 "%02x \n"' |tr -d '\n'`

Using od

`cat patternfile.txt |od -A none -t x1|tr -d '\n'`

and pipe it into (common for both hexdump and od)
`|sed 's:[ ]*0a[ ]*$::g'|sed 's: 0a:\\|:g' |sed 's:^[ ]*::g'|sed 's:^: :g' |sed 's: :\\x:g'`
then pipe result into 
`|sed 's:^:\\(:g' |sed 's:$:\\):g'`
and you have a regexp pattern that is escaped.

---

### 2. Feed the escaped pattern into broken regexp

Assuming the bare minimum shell escape is available,
we use `grep "$(echo -en "ESCAPED_PATTERN" )"` to do our job.

---

### 3. To sum it up

Building a escaped regexp pattern (using hexdump as example )

> `grep "$(echo -en "$( cat patternfile.txt |hexdump -ve '1/1 "%02x \n"' |tr -d '\n' |sed 's:[ ]*0a[ ]*$::g'|sed 's: 0a:\\|:g' |sed 's:^[ ]*::g'|sed 's:^: :g' |sed 's: :\\x:g'|sed 's:^:\\(:g' |sed 's:$:\\):g')")"`

will escape all characters and enclose it with (|) brackets so a regexp OR match will be performed.

### 4. Recrusive directory lookup

Under normal situations, even when `grep -r` is broken, `find /dir/ -exec grep {} \;` should work.
Some may prefer `xargs` instaed (unless you happen to have buggy xargs).
We prefer `find /somedir/ -type f -print0 |xargs -0 grep -f 'patternfile.txt'` approach, but since 
this is not available (for whatever valid reason), 
we need to exec `grep` for each file,and this is normaly the wrong way.
But lets do it.

Assume : `find -type f` works. 
Assume : `xargs` is broken OR not available.

First, if you have a buggy pipe, it might not handle large number of files.
So we avoid `xargs` in such systems (i know, i know, just lets pretend it is broken ).

`find /whatever/dir/to/start/looking/ -type f > list-of-all-file-to-search-for.txt`

IF your shell handles large size lists nicely, 
`for file in cat list-of-all-file-to-search-for.txt ; do grep REGEXP_PATTERN "$file" ;
done ;`  is a nice way to get by. Unfortunetly, some systems do not like that,
and in that case, you may require 
`cat list-of-all-file-to-search-for.txt | split --help -a 4 -d -l 2000 file-smaller-chunk.part.`
to turn it into smaller chunks. Now this is for a seriously broken system.
then a `for file in file-smaller-chunk.part.* ; do for single_line in cat "$file" ; do grep REGEXP_PATTERN "$single_line" ; done ; done ;`
should work.

A
 `cat filelist.txt |while read file ; do grep REGEXP_PATTERN $file ; done ;`
may be used as workaround on some systems.

What if my shell doe not handle quotes ?

You may have to escape the file list beforehand.

It can be done much nicer in `awk`, `perl`, whatever, but since we restrict our selves to
`sed`, lets do it.
We assume `0x27, the ' code`  will actually work.
`cat list-of-all-file-to-search-for.txt |sed 's@['\'']@'\''\\'\'\''@g'|sed 's:^:'\'':g'|sed 's:$:'\'':g'`
The only time I had to use this was when feeding output into bash again.

What if my shell does not handle that ?

`xargs` fails , `grep -r` fails , shell's for loop fails.

Do we have other things ? YES.

Escape all input suitable for your shell, and make a script.

But you know what, I got board, and writing automated scripts for csh just seems
wrong. So I am going to stop here.

### Take home note

Use the tool for the right job. Writing a interpreter on `bc` is perfectly
capable, but it is just plain wrong. Install coreutils, `perl`, a better `grep`
what ever. makes life a better thing.